# В запросе нужно убрать записи, которые повторяются

Tags: ms-access

Есть база Библиотека, Абоненты, Выдача книг.
Был создан запрос Хорошие абоненты: это те абоненты, в которых ДАТА ВЫДАЧИ-ДАТА ВОЗВРАТА<=14. Некоторые абоненты прочитали несколько книг и соответственно в запросе есть повторяющиеся фамилии.
ВОПРОС: как сделать так, чтобы абонент отображался только один раз, независимо от того, сколько дат у него <=14 ???

Comment: [DISTINCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-microsoft-access-sql)

Comment: Я уже читала про эту функцию, но незнаю как ее применить. У меня такое:

Comment: SELECT DISTINCTROW [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Группа, [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Фамилия, [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Имя, [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Отчество, [К_10_Выдача книг].[Дата выдачи], [К_10_Выдача книг].[Дата возврата]
FROM [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки] INNER JOIN [К_10_Выдача книг] ON [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].[Код абонента] = [К_10_Выдача книг].[Код абонента]

Comment: GROUP BY [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Группа, [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Фамилия, [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Имя, [К_10_Абоненты библиотеки].Отчество, [К_10_Выдача книг].[Дата выдачи], [К_10_Выдача книг].[Дата возврата]
HAVING (((DateDiff("d",[Дата выдачи],[Дата возврата]))<=14));

Comment: Можно ли не через SQL, а через конструктор как то это сделать? Заранее огромное спасибо )))

Comment: Специалисты не видят ваших данных, по этому действуют наугад. Покажите минимум исходных данных, в текстовом виде (таблица) , и какой результат вы хотите увидеть. И какая база данных

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cTpEsTIogsbsIIgYDsv_UfL17ic-cuGh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Там очень много данных. Я незнаю как их показать, если только не отправить всю базу.

Answer (score 0):

> ВОПРОС: как сделать так, чтобы абонент отображался только один раз,
> независимо от того, сколько дат у него <=14 ???

Если это полный вопрос, и требуется выбрать из таблицы "Хорошие абоненты"

```
SELECT `Фамилия`, `Имя`, `Отчество` 
FROM `К_10_Хорошие абоненты` 
GROUP BY `К_10_Хорошие абоненты`.`Фамилия`, `К_10_Хорошие абоненты`.`Имя`, `К_10_Хорошие абоненты`.`Отчество`
```

или можно уточнить вопрос.

Если нужно соединить таблицу "Хорошие абоненты" с таблицей "Абоненты библиотеки", можно так

```
SELECT DISTINCT  t2.`Фамилия`, t2.`Имя`, t2.`Группа`, t2.`Город`, t2.`Номер телефона`
FROM `К_10_Хорошие абоненты` as t1 LEFT JOIN  `К_10_Абоненты библиотеки` as t2 on t1.`Фамилия`=t2.`Фамилия`
```